# Convert object-type hours:minutes:seconds column to datetime type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, object, dtype

I have a column called `Time` in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
599359    12:32:25
326816    17:55:22
326815    17:55:22
358789    12:48:25
361553    12:06:45
            ...   
814512    21:22:07
268266    18:57:31
659699    14:28:20
659698    14:28:20
268179    17:48:53
Name: Time, Length: 546967, dtype: object
```

And right now it is an `object` dtype. I've tried the following to convert it to a datetime:

`df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce', utc = True).dt.time`

And I understand that the `.dt.time` methods are needed to prevent the Year and Month from being added, but I believe this is causing the dtype to revert to an object.

Any workarounds? I know I could do

`df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce', utc = True)`

but I have over 500,000 rows and this is taking forever.

Comment: This is causing the dtype to revert to an object - yes. Any workarounds? No. pandas datetime does not handle date and time separately. Why do you want to get rid of the date in the first place? Maybe answering that question first can lead to a better option.

Comment: There seems to be something odd happening. With 500,000 randomly generated times as strings (which you have as type object) it takes less me than 1sec to convert to Pandas TimeStamp using your code.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this bit: `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce', utc = True).dt.time`, you're converting the `'Time'` column to have `pd.dtype` as `object`... and that "object" is the python type `datetime.time`.

The pandas dtype `pd.datetime` is a different type than python's `datetime.datetime` objects. And pandas' `pd.datetime` does not support `time` objects (i.e. you can't have pandas consider the column a datetime without providing the year). This is the dtype is changing to `object`.

In the case of your second approach, `df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce', utc = True)` there is something slightly different happening. In this case you're applying the `pd.to_datetime` to each scalar element of the `'Time'` series. Take a [look at the return types of the function in the docs,](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) but basically in this case the time values in your df are being converted to `pd.datetime` objects on the 1st of january 1900. (i.e. a default date is added).

So: pandas is behaving correctly. If you only want the times, then it's okay to use the `datetime.time` objects in the column. But to operate on them you'll probably be relying on many [slow] `df.apply` methods. Alternatively, just keep the default date of `1900-01-01` and then you can add/subtract the `pd.datetime` columns and get the speed advantage of pandas. Then just strip off the date when you're done with it.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the answer. I am trying to add this Time column with a Date column, and I’m getting an error because Date is a datetime type and Time is still Object. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: Ah okay so one column contains time (as a string) and one column contains a date. You want to combine these into `datetime`.

Most recommended way is to keep everything in pandas dtypes because that's fastest. If you convert the Time column to pd.timedelta using `pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"], errors="coerce")` then then you can just add this column to any pd.datetime column like `df["Datetime"] = df["Time"] + df["Date"]`. If that column that stores date is not a pd.datetime column (maybe it's python datetime.date column for example), then make sure to convert it first, using pd.to_datetime.